# Recursively create a dictionary of AWS EC2 instance metadata with Flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would love some advice on a project I am working on. What I am trying to do is to create a startup script and a python web app for AWS instances which will display all the instance metadata details on the index page. I think this will be helpful if we are working with and troubleshooting multiple instances behind a load balancer or working with containers. I was able to pull this off for GCP since they had a recursive call in their API which spat out all details.

With AWS, all the instance data is stored in this address http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/, what this returns is a set of folders which each contain specific information or more folders with more information. What I am trying to do is build an algorithm that recursively makes API calls and builds a nested dictionary in the process so we can convert that dictionary into JSON and display it in the web page.

I have shared the GitHub repo here, let me know if there is an easier way to do this, I might be over complicating it. Any advice or suggestions are welcome.

https://github.com/RaguRJ/aws_instance_detail_flask_app

## Snippet of the main.py code below

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
import json


app = Flask(__name__)

# func to recursively return paths
metadata_server = "http://169.254.169.254/latest/"
metadata = {}
path_dict = {}
temp_dict = {}

def api_gen(key, url):
    value = requests.get(url).text
    path_list = [x for x in value.splitlines()]
    parent_key = key
    #print('api_gen url: ', url)
    return parent_key, {parent_key : path_list}, path_list



def met_gen(key, path_list, url):
    for p in path_list:
        # path_dict.update({ p : ''})
        print('p', p)
        if p[-1] != '/':
           api_call = api_gen(p, url+p)
           return api_call[1]
        else:
           api_call = api_gen(p, url+p)
           print('api_call[0]: ', api_call[0])
           print('api_call[2]: ', api_call[2])
           print('url: ', url+api_call[0])
           return met_gen(api_call[0], api_call[2], url+api_call[0])
    return

path_list = ["meta-data/"]
path_dict.update(met_gen(None, path_list, metadata_server))
json_data = json.dumps(path_dict, indent=4)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html', json_data=json_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

I am trying to recursively call the met_gen function until we hit the final value in a folder branch. This gets all the details stored in the instance, but the formatting is not perfect where its either creating duplicate copies or creating new entries in the main dictionary instead of creating nested dictionary items.

Comment: You should be very cautious in which metadata you show on this web page. The metadata contains, for example, STS tokens (credentials) which you should definitely *not* expose. Personally, I'm not sure that exposing any of the metadata in this way would be so helpful that it's worth the effort and the risk. If you're convinced it is, however, be aware of a Python package: https://pypi.org/project/ec2-metadata/

Comment: Hey Ajay, thanks for the edit and comment. This app is strictly to be used for lab purposes. But again, it's not advisable to include sensitive information (thanks for pointing out). I have modified the code to remove any sensitive information from the JSON. Also I checked out the ec2-metadata module, I could not find anything that returned all the details that I needed in one call. I figured out the recursive function algorithm I needed to update the nested dictionary, I will update the question with that information soon.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the recursive functions that were needed to create the nested dictionary

- api_gen() function takes in a key and an URL and returns the parent_key and a list of values returned from the AWS internal meta-data server
- met_gen() function recursively runs through all paths in the meta-server and makes calls to api_gen() and update() functions
- update() Update function gets a dictionary, key and a value as an input. This function recursively searches any number of levels in a nested dictionary and updates the key with the given value.
- Once the final nested dictionary is generated any sensitive values are deleted from the dictionary
- The dictionary is then converted into a JSON objec
- The JSON object is sent to the 'index.html' file through the flask app and is rendered as a pre-formatted text

Main.py coded included below

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
import json


app = Flask(__name__)

# global variable initialization
metadata_server = "http://169.254.169.254/latest/"
path_dict = {"meta-data/" : ''}
temp_dict = {}

# function that returns a key and a list of value/values from the metadata server
def api_gen(key, url):
    value = requests.get(url).text
    path_list = [x for x in value.splitlines()]
    parent_key = key
    return parent_key, path_list


# recursive function that goes through each folder level in the metadata api
def met_gen(path_list, url):
    for p in path_list:
        if p[-1] != '/':
           api_call = api_gen(p, url+p)
           update(path_dict, api_call[0], api_call[1])
        else:
           api_call = api_gen(p, url+p)
           temp_dict = { k:[] for k in api_call[1]}
           update(path_dict, api_call[0], temp_dict)
           met_gen(api_call[1], url+api_call[0])
    return

# recursive function that finds a key in a nested dictionary and updates its value
def update(dic, key, value):
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if k == key:
            dic[k] = value
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            update(dic.get(k), key, value)
        elif not k in dic.keys():
            dic.update({ key : value })
    return

#  initializing path_list and calling met_gen function
path_list = ["meta-data/"]
met_gen(path_list, metadata_server)

# Deleting sensitive information from the dictionary
del path_dict["meta-data/"]["identity-credentials/"]
del path_dict["meta-data/"]["public-keys/"]

json_data = json.dumps(path_dict, indent=4)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html', json_data=json_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```